# How do I get two adjacent spans to display their text vertically?

Tags: html, css

So I have this HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6"> <span class="currency-symbol">$</span><span class="price">44</span>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p>/ month</p>
                <p>Here are some really interesting things about the product.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then this CSS

```
.container {
    width: 333px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.currency-symbol {
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 33px;
}
.price {
    font-size: 88px;
    vertical-align: top; /* doesn't work */
}
```

The '$' symbol aligns to the top as does the text in the RH column. But the price amount doesn't.

How do I vertically align the '$' symbol, the '44' amount and the text in the RH column so that they're all in line?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/magician11/4k19w0fs/3/

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, the number '44' doesn't look like it's at the top because its text size is much bigger than the other stuff. How exactly do you want it to look?

Comment: Play with `line-height` for `.price` and `.currency-symbol` a little bit - make it less than font size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try line-height on your price class

```
.price {
    font-size: 88px;
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was nice and simple. Yes, I was trying to get the '$' symbol, the number '44' and the text in the RH column to all align.

Comment: As a matter of interest, why don't I need the vertical-align for this 'price' class?

Comment: I believe they're already at the top because they don't take up all the room on the top line. Once you add more spans, they will eventually go under them

Answer (score 1):

It actually *does* work, just it doesn't look like it.

Highlight the "44" and you'll see the highlight extends quite a way beyond the top of the digits. The only real way to do this is going to be fine-tuning the `line-height`s, or `margin-top`s of each element.

```
.price {
    line-height:77px;
}
```

That seems pretty close to me. Note that other fonts (or even other digits) might be different.

Answer (score 0):

try to edit price class like this?

```
.price {
font-size: 88px;
vertical-align: top;
position: relative;
left:5px;
top:-22px;
}
```

I am not entirely sure what you are asking for though... maybe this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

Just make the line-height: 1; on the .price span to give it the same alignment as space-height.

```
.price {
    font-size: 88px;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

This aligns each of the elements. However, I also recommend looking-up vertical rhythm and how to get textual elements to maintain the same vertical space.